# Переменное количество параметров

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Необходимо передать в функцию переменное количество параметров одного типа. Проблема в том, что тип сам является классом с переменным числом параметров. Вот как выглядит класс:

```
template <typename... Types, int... Int_pack>
class MyType<std::tuple<Types...>, std::tuple<Int_pack...>>
{
//...
};
```

Требуется так объявить функцию `template<...> void foo(...)`, чтобы она могла принимать переменное количество параметров типа `MyType`. Пробовал делать что-то в духе:

```
template <typename... Types, int... Int_pack>
void foo(const MyType<std::tuple<Types...>, std::tuple<Int_pack...>>& args_pack...)
{
//...
}
```

Это единственный вариант, который не выдает ошибки, но передается в итоге только первый параметр. Пробовал использовать 3 шаблонных параметра, но безуспешно. Подскажите, как сделать правильно.

Comment: А почему не `std::vector<T>` или `std::initializer_list<T>`?

Comment: @VladD как с помощью них можно передать переменное количество параметров?

Comment: Ну, вы упаковываете параметры в точке вызова в контейнер, и передаёте контейнер вместо этого, например. Меняете сигнатуру функции, чтобы она принимала контейнер. Топорное, но рабочее решение.

Comment: @VladD да, понял, в данном конкретном случае так можно сделать, потому что тип один, но все другие функции, вообще говоря, принимают разные типы, так что нужен именно такой интерфейс

Comment: @grigoriy что в итоге надо: любое кол-во любых типов `MyType` или любое кол-во из одинаковых `MyType`?

Answer (score 1):

1. Не вполне понимаю что вы хотите сказать вот этим

`class MyType<std::tuple<Types...>, std::tuple<Int_pack...>>`

Что это? Спецификация шаблона какая-то хитрая? В любом случае в данном конкретном виде этот код компилятор не понимает. Вы делаете что-то не так. Объясните задачу чётче.

2. Попробую всё же ответить на ваш оригинальный вопрос.

Для того чтобы передать в функцию переменное количество параметров типа T можно сделать следующее:

- [Variadic Arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic) - крайне не рекомендую.
- Шаблон который принимает любой похожий на контейнер объект

Например:

```
template <typename T, typename Container = std::vector<T>> 
void foo(const Container& args)
{
    // Container type has to be iterable
    // i.e. has begin() and end() methods or std::begin() and std::end() can be applied
    // arg is some container-like object (variable length)  of objects of type T.
    for (const auto& sub_arg : arg) 
    {
        //sub_arg is an element of type const T&
    }
}
```

Теперь можно делать вот так:

```
foo<int>({ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 });
```

или вот так:

```
std::set<int> a{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
foo<decltype(a)::value_type>(a);
```

и даже так:

```
int b[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
foo<int>(b);
```